# tailwind css into variants - framer motion

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

How to use tailwind css classes into framer motion objects..

```
const variant = {
    hidden: {
      'w-0'
    },
    visible: {
      width: 400,
      transition: {
        type: 'spring',
        stiffness: 170,
        damping:30,
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex relative w-full h-full'>

      <button className='absolute z-40 top-0 left-0 origin-left bg-white rounded-lg px-6 py-2'>Open</button>

      <motion.div variants={variant} initial="hidden" animate="visible"  className="flex absolute bg-gray-100 top-0 bottom-0 ">
        some
      </motion.div>
      

    </div>
  )
```

in the above example, i would like to use in "hidden" property any tailwind css class but no idea how to implement it. "w-0" should be my approach but like i show it in that code it doesnt works

Answer (score 2):

you'd be able to do that by using [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro)

```
    import tw from 'twin.macro'

    const variant = {
    hidden: {
      tw`w-0`
    },
    visible: {
      width: 400,
      transition: {
        type: 'spring',
        stiffness: 170,
        damping:30,
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex relative w-full h-full'>

      <button className='absolute z-40 top-0 left-0 origin-left bg-white rounded-lg px-6 py-2'>Open</button>

      <motion.div variants={variant} initial="hidden" animate="visible"  className="flex absolute bg-gray-100 top-0 bottom-0 ">
        some
      </motion.div>
      

    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tailwind to create css variables which can then be used with framer motion. You can target breakpoints as well.

```html
export function Sample(){
    return (
        <div className='flex relative w-full h-full'>
            <button className='absolute z-40 top-0 left-0 origin-left bg-white rounded-lg px-6 py-2'>
                Open
            </button>
            <motion.div
                className="flex absolute top-0 bottom-0 bg-slate-600 h-40 [--width-from: 0px] max-sm:[--width-to:200px] [--width-to:600px]"
                variants={{
                    hidden: {
                        width: "var(--width-from)",
                    },
                    visible: {
                        width: "var(--width-to)",
                        transition: {
                            type: 'spring',
                            stiffness: 170,
                            damping: 30,
                            duration: 2,
                        }
                    }
                }}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="visible">
                some
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Nice find... I've found the docs after seeing this post - it's not the easiest to find.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think that this is possible to achieve
The best way is to do what you want is

```
const variant = {
    hidden: {
      // Property width directly
      width:0
    },
    visible: {
      width: 400,
      transition: {
        type: 'spring',
        stiffness: 170,
        damping:30,
      }
    }
  }
```